# How to specialize a traits class for T as well as all of T's descendants

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization, type-traits

I want to make a traits class apply to a type as well as its descedants.  Is this possible?

```
template <typename E>
struct Garble {
};

template <typename T>
struct wooble_traits;

template <typename E>
struct wooble_traits<Garble<E>> {
  typedef E elem_type;
};

struct IntGarble : public Garble<int> {
};

typedef typename wooble_traits<IntGarble>::elem_type IGType;
//Error, wooble_traits<IntGarble> has no definition.
```

Is there some way to instead say (borrowing and abusing Java notation):

```
template <typename E>
struct wooble_traits<? extends Garble<E>> {
  typedef E elem_type
};

typedef typename wooble_traits<IntGarble>::elem_type IGType;
//Fine, IGType is an alias for int
```

---

Note:
Attempting to adapt Dyp's solution to my example doesn't work since Garble takes a type parameter.  There doesn't seem to be anywhere to infer that parameter.

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>

template <typename T, typename C = void>
struct wooble_traits;

template <typename T, typename E>
struct wooble_traits<T, typename boost::is_base_of<Garble<E>, T>::type> {
  typedef E elem_type;
};
```

in gcc-4.6 this produces:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/boost/utility -I/usr/include/boost/type_traits -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp:15:8: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
../main.cpp:15:8: error:         ‘E’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

which is understandable since there's no way for GCC to know the value of E.

Comment: @Jefffrey: eg `IntGarble`. a subclass / derived class.

Comment: By descendant I mean derived class.  A traits class makes information about a type available at compile-time.  wooble_traits exposes a wooble's elem_type to be used at compile-time.  When viewed as a wooble, a Garble has elem_type same as its template argument.  All derived classes from some Garble (including IntGarble) have the same elem_type as their Garble ancestor (in the case of IntGarble, this type is int).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For base *classes*:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool b>
using stdbool_t = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<class T, class U = std::true_type>
struct trait
    : std::false_type
{};

struct foo {};
struct bar : foo {};

template<class T>
struct trait<T, stdbool_t<std::is_base_of<foo, T>{}>>
    : std::true_type
{};


#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << trait<int>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << trait<foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << trait<bar>::value << "\n";
}
```

For some reason, specializing on non-type template parameters isn't allowed when the expression depends on (the previous) type parameters.

g++4.8.2 fails to compile this btw (ICE), but it [works fine with clang++3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e62949a9883eee)

---

Here's an alternative version that compiles on both compilers:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct trait
    : std::false_type
{};

struct foo {};
struct bar : foo {};

template<class T>
struct trait<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<foo, T>{}>::type>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

The `enable_if` isn't necessary, actually. A `std::conditional` would work as well, but the `enable_if` is shorter here.

---

If the base is a template specialization, we can use [Jarod42's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592618/420683) (I've modified it a bit):

```
template<template<class...> class T, class U>
struct is_base_template_of
{
private:
    template<class... V>
    static auto test(const T<V...>&)
        -> decltype(static_cast<const T<V...>&>(std::declval<U>()),
                    std::true_type{});

    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value =
        decltype(is_base_template_of::test(std::declval<U>()))::value;
};


template<class T>
struct trait<T,
             typename std::enable_if<is_base_template_of<foo, T>::value>::type>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

Note: this only works for public inheritance (and I think it has some further restrictions: virtual and some cases of multiple inheritance shouldn't work either).

---

Here's a version of the same type trait in "C++03 + boost" style:

```
template<template<class> class T, class U>
struct is_base_template_of
{
private:
    typedef char false_type;
    typedef char(& true_type)[2];

    template<class V>
    static true_type test(const T<V>*);
    static false_type test(...);

public:
    static const bool value =
       (   sizeof(test(std::declval<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type*>()))
        == sizeof(true_type));
};
```

Comment: Ok, but how about when foo takes a template parameter (as in my example).  How do you do it then? (without forcing the client to know the type of that parameter)

Comment: @dspyz Oops, sry, I've simplified the test case too much. Added a solution where the base class is a template specialization.

Comment: Ok, this looks good, but the project I'm working on doesn't use C++11 (as you might have guessed from my boost-based examples).  Is there some way to do this without decltype?

Comment: Oh, boost has a TYPEOF macro which looks like it does the same thing.  I'll test it to see if it works.

Comment: @dspyz The `decltype` part just makes SFINAE a bit more convenient. I'll try to replace it with old-fashioned SFINAE.

Comment: @dspyz Try the version in "C++03 + boost" style

Comment: I replaced std::declval<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type*> with (U*) 0. It compiles, but now I can't figure out how to retrieve the template parameter (as you remember, I wanted to make traits::elem_type be an alias for E (V in your example)).  But by using is_base_template_of, that information gets lost.

Comment: `declval` can be easily implemented in C++03: `template<class T> T declval();` (the difference to C++11 is that the latter return `T&&`). Retrieving the template parameter can be done with a deduction very similar to the one used in my post, I'll add an example.

Comment: @dspyz [`boost` also has a `declval`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/declval.html). The example isn't as easy as I thought, since I may not use `decltype` :( Inside the `test` function, the template parameter is known, so you can always write a similar function and inside use the template parameter. Not sure if you can get it *out* of the function, though.

Comment: Well, this has gotten far more complicated and involved than I'm willing to tolerate any way.  I wanted to do this without any change to existing classes, but it's not worth the extra effort at this point.  I'm just going to add a typedef E elem_type directly to the classes themselves (rather than having a separate traits class).  They're already so bloated with code that doesn't belong, 2 or 3 extra lines might even go unnoticed.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer since no one else seems to have any other ideas and I learned a lot from it.