# Checking template parameter inheritance with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, sfinae

I have a helper class `R<T>`, and some classes `T` inherit it. I want to declare some function `f(T t)` for those classes which do not inherit `R<T>`. This is done easily with SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
class R {};

class Good : public R<Good> {};
class Bad {};

template<typename T>
auto f(T /* t */) -> typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<R<T>, T>::value>::type
{
    // do something
}

int main() {
    f(Good()); // compilation error
    f(Bad()); // OK
}
```

Now I have some other class `Derived` which inherits `Good`. It does not inherit `R<Derived>` though. Still, I do not want to declare `f(Derived)`.

```
class Derived : public Good {};

int main() {
    f(Derived()); // OK, but should be compilation error
}
```

So, what I want to check for type `T` is that `T` is a descendant of some `R<P>` where `P` is some parent of `T`.

Is it possible to do it with SFINAE? I'd like to stay within the scope of C++11.

Although I'm really interested in how to solve this general problem, in my exact case there is one simplification: I know that among all parents of `T` there is at most one `R<P>` for any `P`. Any solution for this simplification is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that I solved it, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592618/2159939):

```
template<template<typename> class Base, typename Derived>
struct SmartBaseOf {
private:
    template<class Intermediate>
    static auto test(const Base<Intermediate>&) -> typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_base_of<Intermediate, Derived>::value &&
                std::is_base_of<Base<Intermediate>, Intermediate>::value,
            std::true_type>::type;

    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    constexpr static bool value = decltype(test(Derived()))::value;
};  

template<typename T>
auto f(T /* t */) -> typename std::enable_if<
    !SmartBaseOf<R, T>::value>::type
{   
    // do something
}
```