# How to template on a container type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have two functions

```
template <class T> void foo(std::vector<T>* p)
```

and

```
template <class T> void foo(std::valarray<T>* p)
```

The code in the function bodies is identical. Is there a clever way of writing the template so I can avoid the duplication? Something like

```
template <class T, class Container> void foo(Container<T>* p)
```

I'm using C++14.

I *only* want to allow `Container` to be either `std::vector` or `std::valarray`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. My brain is to fuzzy to apply that. Trying...

Comment: I want it to *only* apply to either a std::vector or a std::valarray.

Comment: Then write a overload.

Comment: Write a helper function (possibly hidden in some internal namespace) like `template <typename Container> void fooHelper(Container* p);` Have the two `foo` overloads call it.

Comment: `template <template<class> class C, class T>` and `std::enable_if<>`

Comment: why do you want to apply it only for `std::vector` and `std::valarray` ? because there are other overloads for other containers? Or because the code in the function body only works for those two?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: It's because of other overloads for other containers. I'm wondering if I can put the functions in a certain order and use `template<template<class> class Container, class T>`?

Comment: Do you really care the implementations of containers or you care about the functions provided by containers? They are different. I suggest to show how you use these containers. Eg: indexing, `front()`/`back()`...

Comment: What is wrong with simple: `template <class T> void foo(T* p)`? Do you have other overloads of `foo`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create type traits only for your case.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct is_vector_or_valarray : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_vector_or_valarray<std::vector<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_vector_or_valarray<std::valarray<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename C, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_vector_or_valarray<C>::value>>
void foo(C* p) {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oWT4zdWf5)

---

If you want to allow classes derived from `std::vector` and `std::valarray` passed in.

```cpp
template<template<typename...> typename T, typename U>
struct is_tbase_of
{
private:
    template<class V>
    static std::pair<V, decltype(static_cast<const T<V>&>(std::declval<U>()), std::true_type{})> test(const T<V>&);
    static std::pair<U, std::false_type> test(...);
public:
    using _aux_type = decltype(test(std::declval<U>()));
    using base_type = T<typename _aux_type::first_type>;
    static constexpr bool value = _aux_type::second_type::value;
};


template<typename C,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<
                        is_tbase_of<std::vector, C>::value
                        || is_tbase_of<std::valarray, C>::value>>
void foo(C* p) {
    using base_t = std::conditional_t<
                    is_tbase_of<std::vector, C>::value,
                    typename is_tbase_of<std::vector, C>::base_type,
                    typename is_tbase_of<std::valarray, C>::base_type>;
    auto pbase = static_cast<base_t*>(p);

    // operate on pbase
}
```

The type traits for checking if a class inherits from a template class comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592618/8649091). I make some subtle changes based on it(mainly for getting the base type).

As @Raymond says, `c` should be cast to its base pointer to operate on the sliced part. I believe it should be done in the function body, otherwise, there'll be a non-deduced context.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jbr1anEqe)

Comment: Fails for `struct S:std::vector<int>{} s; foo(&s);` You probably have to `enable_if` on `is_convertible` (and then cast to `std::vector<T>*` to ensure you operate on the slice, like the original function did). Better would be to `enable_if` on some property of `vector` and `valarray` that the underlying algorithm relies on (e.g. having a `value_type` and a subscript operator).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for pointing it out. Wil something like `std::is_base_of` be enough in such case rather than `std::is_convertible`? I'll try to fix it when I have time a bit later.

Comment: I updated my answer at least to meet the derived class pointer requirement, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Note: you cannot really specialize on `std::vector<>` and `std::valarray<>`, but you can say, for the given (deduced) T, you expect `std::vector<T>` or `std::valarray<T>`. Thus aliases will also be resolved.

The trick is, you templetize for a template class `C` and a type `T` (and possibly further parameters, as in `std`), then use `std::enable_if<>` that only resolves (to void in this case) when either `std::vector<T>` or `std::valarray<T>` was resolved.

Also note, you might want to allow custom allocators et. al., i.e., instead of a single T, it's recommended to use `typename... Ts` for the container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class...> class C, typename T>
auto foo(C<T>* arg) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<C<T>, std::vector<T>>::value || std::is_same<C<T>, std::valarray<T>>::value>
{
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::valarray<int> va;
    //std::pair<int, int> p; // this should fail
    foo(&v);
    foo(&va);
    //foo(&p); // this fails as expected
    return 0;
}
```

If you also want to handle derived classes, you might use `std::is_base_of<>` - but as for classes in `std` namespace, it's not recommended to derive from them.

Comment: Fails for `template<typename T> S:std::vector<T>{}; S<int> s; foo(&s);`

Comment: @RaymondChen Not sure what you mean by `template<typename T> S:std::vector<T>{};`. If you mean `template<typename T> using S = std::vector<T>;`, then it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry. Left out a word. `template<typename T> struct S : std::vector<T> {};` The point is that the `enable_if` is not matching pointers to derived types, but the original functions did.

Comment: @RaymondChen Indeed, but that's a feature, not a bug :). You could, of course match for it - `std::is_base_of<>` -, but the generic rule is not to inherit from std's containers (composition over inheritance).

Comment: It may not be advisable in this situation, but somebody might stumble across this question in another context where derivation is acceptable and try to adapt the solution. (And it should nevertheless be called out as "This isn't exactly the same as the two-overload version, but the places where it's different aren't places you should be going.")

Comment: @RaymondChen Added a sentence to cover this.